# while running maven project i am getting this error

Tags: maven, maven-2, liferay, liferay-6

while running this command

> mvn clean package liferay:depoy

in maven project i am getting this error.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metada
ta.xml
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven
-metadata.xml
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-
metadata.xml (13 KB at 6.9 KB/sec)
Downloaded: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/mojo/maven-metadat
a.xml (20 KB at 9.6 KB/sec)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3.313 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-07-10T14:11:49-04:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 15M/105M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'liferay' in the current project and in the p
lugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the re
positories [local (C:\Users\Nokia_Admin\.m2\repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever plugin you have developed( `portlets, themes, layout templates, hooks or Ext`) you need to navigate to that specific plugin and then fire your command to deploy your plugin.

```
mvn clean package liferay:depoy
```

It is mentioned in your error that maven is not able to find the plugin as your path mentioned is wroong.

Answer (score 0):

Try to include repositories to be downloaded by including this stuff on your pom:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>Liferay-v6.2-CE-(Tomcat-7)</id>
        <properties>
            <liferay.version>Your_Liferay-Version</liferay.version>
            <liferay.maven.plugin.version>6.2.5</liferay.maven.plugin.version>
            <liferay.auto.deploy.dir>/opt/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4/deploy</liferay.auto.deploy.dir>
            <liferay.app.server.deploy.dir>/opt/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps</liferay.app.server.deploy.dir>
            <liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>/opt/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4/tomcat-7.0.42/lib/ext</liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir>
            <liferay.app.server.portal.dir>/opt/liferay-portal-6.2-ce-ga4/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT</liferay.app.server.portal.dir>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```